# How can I get the median value of each product in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, aggregation

I have one table named 'sales'.

```
create table sales
    (
        cust    varchar(20),
        prod    varchar(20),
        day integer,
        month   integer,
        year    integer,
        state   char(2),
        quant   integer
    );
insert into sales values ('Bloom', 'Pepsi', 2, 12, 2001, 'NY', 4232);
insert into sales values ('Knuth', 'Bread', 23, 5, 2005, 'PA', 4167);
insert into sales values ('Emily', 'Pepsi', 22, 1, 2006, 'CT', 4404);
insert into sales values ('Emily', 'Fruits', 11, 1, 2000, 'NJ', 4369);
insert into sales values ('Helen', 'Milk', 7, 11, 2006, 'CT', 210);
insert into sales values ('Emily', 'Soap', 2, 4, 2002, 'CT', 2549);
insert into sales values ('Bloom', 'Eggs', 30, 11, 2000, 'NJ', 559);
```

.... There are 498 rows in total. Here is the overview of this table:

[image]

Now I want to get the median quant for each product. The result table should look like this:

[image]

I have tried these code and it works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _final_median(NUMERIC[])
   RETURNS NUMERIC AS
$$
   SELECT AVG(val)
   FROM (
     SELECT val
     FROM unnest($1) val
     ORDER BY 1
     LIMIT  2 - MOD(array_upper($1, 1), 2)
     OFFSET CEIL(array_upper($1, 1) / 2.0) - 1
   ) sub;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;

CREATE AGGREGATE median(NUMERIC) (
  SFUNC=array_append,
  STYPE=NUMERIC[],
  FINALFUNC=_final_median,
  INITCOND='{}'
);


SELECT prod,round(median(quant)) AS median_quant FROM sales
group by prod
order by prod;
```

But I want to use the 'aggregation' function to get the same result and if there anyway I can do this without special functions?

Answer (score 1):

Median is 0.5-th percentile (value in the middle of the ordered set). You can use `percentile_cont` to calculate it:

```
select percentile_cont(0.50) within group (order by sales.quant)
from sales
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But is there anyway I can do this without using special function? Like write a aggregation function outside the 'groups'?

Comment: @WikizVito why is it a special function? I'm not following.

Comment: Well, it means is there anyway to write a function like this and use With function to combine them rather than using this percentile_cont directly??

Comment: I still have no idea. This has literally the same result as the one you provided...

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _final_median(NUMERIC[])
   RETURNS NUMERIC AS
$$
   SELECT AVG(val)
   FROM (
     SELECT val
     FROM unnest($1) val
     ORDER BY 1
     LIMIT  2 - MOD(array_upper($1, 1), 2)
     OFFSET CEIL(array_upper($1, 1) / 2.0) - 1
   ) sub;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;   Do you have any idea to transfrom this to a understandable query and combine it using the WITH function?？

Comment: @WikizVito what is that?

Comment: This is the code that I posted above in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that aggregate function tries to find the upper median.

In that case a PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) with descending order can be used for the aggregation.

```
select prod, 
 count(*) as total_prod, 
 percentile_disc(0.5) within group (order by quant desc) as ceil_median_quant
from sales
group by prod;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/AWPAH68076)